# In .NET 7, I can't access the image in the project folder

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-7.0

The project is built on .NET 7, and there is no "wwwroot" folder.

[image]

As shown in this picture, the image is present in the project folder. However, when I try to access it from a web browser while the project is running, I encounter this error.

[image]

I want to open the image in a web browser.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to follow the advice from the [ask] page. Please do not use images to show text; instead, include the text in the question. If you are going to include images, *enter an image description* other than "enter image description here".

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check the official documentation at:

1. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=windows#web-root
2. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/generic-host?view=aspnetcore-7.0#webroot
3. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/generic-host?view=aspnetcore-7.0#contentroot

You will probably need to edit your project file as per above given that you do not have a wwwroot folder.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure `UseStaticFiles` middleware in `Program.cs`:

```
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
{
    FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
           Path.Combine(builder.Environment.ContentRootPath, "Content")),
    RequestPath = "/Content"
});
```

Then run the program, you should be able to view the corresponding image in the browser:
[image]

For more details, you can refer to this document: [Serve files outside of web root](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-7.0#serve-files-outside-of-web-root).